# Combine UNION and WITH statement on Azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, union, azure-stream-analytics

I try to combine different sources with the UNION statement on Azure Stream Analytics.
In general, this works fine:

```
SELECT
    date
    , value
FROM source1

UNION 

SELECT
    date
    , value
FROM source2
```

But now I need some calculations which require a WITH statement so I hoped this would work:

```
SELECT
    date
    , value
FROM source1

UNION 

(WITH tempTab AS (
    SELECT
        date
        , value
    FROM source2
SELECT
    date
    , value
FROM tempTab
)
```

(I'm aware that the example for this WITH statement is completely stupid but let's assume I have real world scenario where it is necessary. Let's further assume the WITH statement works on its own, i.e. if I omit the lines from the first select until after UNION)

In this version I get a notification that there is a syntax error near the "WITH" statements. Is there a way to solve the syntax error and make the WITH and UNION statement work together on Stream Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current ASA syntax/semantics,unlike T-SQL, the WITH clause is only allowed to appear first in the query.

You can only do "with step1 as (...), step2 as (...), ..." followed by select clauses using any of step1,step2,... as sources in the from clauses.

union can then be used either in select clauses after the WITH, or inside individual step definitions.

Comment: okay, reorganizing worked: I put the "WITH" statement in front and the rest afterwords. Not it works fine.